# reCaptcha V2 sending email with or without verifying

Tags: php, recaptcha

The issue that I'm having is that the form is successfully submitted whether the reCaptcha is checked or not (I removed the secret key for this post)

Another thing that I would like to change is having the error messages appear on the same page when the user enters invalid responses in the text fields. ReCaptcha is the more important piece for me right now though. Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
     <?php
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'secret key',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

        // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
        echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';
    }
?>
```

This is the submission form php

```
        <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@genysyssolutions.com";
    $email_subject = "Information Regarding Services";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    // create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

header("Location: ThankYou.php");

}
?>
```

Thank You page where they land after clicking "Submit"

```
<?php
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'secret key',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

    // Call the function post_captcha
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

    if (!$res['success']) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
        echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
    } else {
        // If CAPTCHA is successfully completed...

        // Paste mail function or whatever else you want to happen here!
        echo '<br><p>CAPTCHA was completed successfully!</p><br>';
    }
?>

<?php
$title = "ThankYou";

$content = '<div id=thankyou><h2>Thank you for contacting Genysys Solutions!</h2>
<p>
  Please click below to return to the home page!
</p>
<a href="../conctact.php"><div id="starts">
<p>...it starts here</p>
</div></a>
</div>';





include 'Template.php';
?>
```

Contact Form

```
<?php
$title = "Contact";
?>


<?php
$content = '
<div class="contact_head">
<h1>Contact Us!</h1>
<h3>We will get back to you within 24 hours!</h3>
</div>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="SendForm.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Message *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcAT04UAAAAANTzHc_zrVtBmxH_C2x6HakOJuen"></div>
 <br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';

include 'Template.php';


?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to log what's in red after several submit? I.E. empty submit, wrong and correct?

Comment: Which php are you hitting with the form? I see no html here of your form.